# How to pass parameters to Bash getopts using a custom variable as opposed to ${1}, ${2} etc

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments, getopts

I want to specify parameters (options and arguments) in a Bash variable and to pass that variable to `getopts` for parsing instead of the usual variables `${1}`, `${2}` etc. I am not sure how to do this. Often in [documentation for `getopts`](http://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html), the `getopts` syntax is described as follows:

```
Syntax
    getopts optstring name [args]
```

I know that `optstring` represents instructions for `getopts` on how to parse parameters and `name` is a variable that is to store current information under consideration by `getopts` (such as the value of an option's argument), but I do not know what `[args]` is intended to be. Is it a way to pass parameters to `getopts` without using the standard command line variables? If it is, how could I use this facility? If it is not, what would be a good way to pass arguments stored in, say, a space-delimited Bash variable to `getopts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the optional `args` arguments are a way to pass custom parameters. As it says in the manual:

> getopts normally parses the positional parameters, but if more arguments are given in args, getopts parses those instead.

So if you have an array:

```
myargs=(arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

you can use:

```
getopts optstring name "${myargs[@]}"
```

to process them.

Example:

```
$ # Set positional parameters:
$ set -- -a 1 -b
$ getopts a:b var -a 2
$ echo $var
a
$ echo $OPTARG
2
```

As you can see, it retrieved the value from the args I supplied to the command (`2`), not the positional parameters to the shell (`1`)